# How to reload jquery plugin from inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to reload my function from inside, I did a small snippet:

```js
function jqueryPlugin (selector, properties) {
    this.properties = {
        foo: properties.foo || 'foo',
        bar: properties.bar || 'bar'
    };
    // this.element = $(selector);
    // ...
    console.log('element loaded... plugin start working...')
    // ...
    this.reload = function (properties) {
        // ...
        this(selector, properties); // ??
    };
};

var instance = new jqueryPlugin('.foobar', {foo:'foooo'});
// ...
instance.reload({foo:'foobar'});
```

As you can see, it says `this` is not a function. But how can `this` not be a function? What am I missing?

Comment: `But how can this not be a function?` because it's an object. To do what you require, create an `init()` function which you call on load of the plugin and then any point after that you want to re-set it to it's original state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `this` is an object, not a function. Try using an `init` function instead, like @RoryMcCrossan suggested:

```js
function jqueryPlugin (selector, properties) {
    this.init = function(selector, properties){
        this.properties = {
            foo: properties.foo || 'foo',
            bar: properties.bar || 'bar'
        };
        
        //test if `this` is a function: console.log(this);

        // this.element = $(selector);
        // ...
        console.log('element loaded... plugin start working...')
        // ...
    };
    this.reload = function (properties) {
        // ...
        this.init(selector, properties); // ??
    };
    this.init(selector, properties);
};

var instance = new jqueryPlugin('.foobar', {foo:'foooo'});
// ...
instance.reload({foo:'foobar'});
```